# How do i remove duplicate address line in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have org_name, add_line1 , add_line2, add_line3 which i have put on different lines by using

```
(RTRIM(org_name) || CHR(32) || NVL2(RTRIM(org_name), CHR(32) || '\line' || CHR(32), '') ||
RTRIM(add_line1) || CHR(32) || NVL2(RTRIM(add_line1), CHR(32) || '\line' || CHR(32), '') ||
RTRIM(add_line2) || CHR(32) || NVL2(RTRIM(add_line2), CHR(32) || '\line' || CHR(32), '') ||
RTRIM(add_line3) || CHR(32) || NVL2(RTRIM(add_line3), CHR(32) || '\line' || CHR(32), '') || )AS "POSTAL_ADDRESS"
```

The problem is sometimes `org_name` is same as `add_line1` meaning in the output I am getting the name twice on lines 1 and 2.

What I can't figure out is how to show name once if line output is same as line2 output.

Can someone please help me on this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a case-insensitive and having no space problem comparison might be made by using `regexp_like()` and `trim()` functions together :

```
case when regexp_like(trim(org_name),trim(add_line1),'i') 
     then 
          org_name 
     else add_line1 
      end as org_name
```

**or** you may try within concatenation of `POSTAL ADDRESS` string as

```
select line_no, case when regexp_like(trim(org_name),trim(add_line1),'i') then 
           rtrim(org_name) || chr(32) || nvl2(rtrim(org_name), chr(32) || '\line' || chr(32), '') 
       else 
           rtrim(org_name) || chr(32) || nvl2(rtrim(org_name), chr(32) || '\line' || chr(32), '') ||
           rtrim(add_line1)|| chr(32) || nvl2(rtrim(add_line1), chr(32)|| '\line' || chr(32), '' 
       ) 
       end as "POSTAL_ADDRESS" 
  from tab
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=14a59514de34cb15cafc6256a5918a41)</kbd>

Comment: hi, this works when org_name and add_line1 are same but its ignoring org_name when its different from add_line1. How do i handle that scenario at the same time?

Comment: hi @K124 . Can you give a sample, please ? Maybe better on the fiddle.

Comment: hi, thanks for your response. I am new here and i really dont know how i send an image :-(

Comment: mostly people use imgur hard to see i.stack.imgur.com for sharing images, but most of the answerers(including me) do not prefer images. Besides, I cannot see the images through my office's internet because of some firewall filterings. Rather you can edit your question with some text @K124

Comment: I think i have figured out the issue. Just need to slightly change the else statement  @Barbaros Özhan.                                                               
 ELSE  RTRIM(org_name) || CHR(32) || '\line' || CHR(32)|| RTRIM(add_line1) END AS org_name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202566/discussion-between-k124-and-barbaros-ozhan).

Answer (score 0):

Using `CASE` (or `DECODE`), e.g.

```
case when org_name <> add_line1 then <value you want to return)
     else null
end
```